# RequestError: Timeout awaiting 'request' for 30000ms youtube-dl

Tags: discord.js, youtube-dl

I just want it to play the song although it plays the song for about 20 seconds and then stops and gives me the following error:

```
RequestError: Timeout awaiting 'request' for 30000ms

2021-02-20T07:55:21.000350+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/index.js:953:65)
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000351+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000352+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:327:22)
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000353+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at ClientRequest.origin.emit (/app/node_modules/@szmarczak/http-timer/dist/source/index.js:39:20)
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000353+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:469:9)
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000354+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000354+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000354+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000355+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000356+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Timeout.timeoutHandler [as _onTimeout] (/app/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/utils/timed-out.js:36:25)
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000356+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:556:17)
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000356+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000357+00:00 app[worker.1]:   name: 'TimeoutError',
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000357+00:00 app[worker.1]:   code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000358+00:00 app[worker.1]:   timings: {
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000358+00:00 app[worker.1]:     start: 1613807690995,
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000359+00:00 app[worker.1]:     socket: 1613807690995,
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000359+00:00 app[worker.1]:     lookup: 1613807690996,
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000360+00:00 app[worker.1]:     connect: 1613807690998,
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000360+00:00 app[worker.1]:     secureConnect: 1613807691002,
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000360+00:00 app[worker.1]:     upload: 1613807691002,
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000361+00:00 app[worker.1]:     response: 1613807691027,
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000361+00:00 app[worker.1]:     end: undefined,
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000361+00:00 app[worker.1]:     error: 1613807720997,
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000362+00:00 app[worker.1]:     abort: 1613807720999,
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000362+00:00 app[worker.1]:     phases: {
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000363+00:00 app[worker.1]:       wait: 0,
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000363+00:00 app[worker.1]:       dns: 1,
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000363+00:00 app[worker.1]:       tcp: 2,
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000364+00:00 app[worker.1]:       tls: 4,
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000364+00:00 app[worker.1]:       request: 0,
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000364+00:00 app[worker.1]:       firstByte: 25,
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000365+00:00 app[worker.1]:       download: undefined,
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000365+00:00 app[worker.1]:       total: 30004
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000365+00:00 app[worker.1]:     }
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000366+00:00 app[worker.1]:   },
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000366+00:00 app[worker.1]:   event: 'request'
2021-02-20T07:55:21.000366+00:00 app[worker.1]: }
```

Here is part of my code were it would of probably errored out or the timeout thingy:

```
 setTimeout(async function() {
      dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(url))
      .on('finish', () => {
        y = number.get(`y`);
        number = editJsonFile(`number/${message.guild.id}.json`);
        number.set(`y`, y+1);
        number.save();
        checker = editJsonFile(`checker/${message.guild.id}.json`);
        checker.set(`checker`, checking--);
        checker.save();
        voiceChannel.leave();

        try {
          delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./queue.js`)];

          let commandFile = require(`./queue.js`);
          commandFile.run(client, message, args);
        } catch(e) {
          console.log(e.stack);
        }

      })
      .on('error', error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
      dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(5 / 5);
      message.channel.send(" Playing...");
    }, 2000);
    }
  }
```

I want it to play normally using youtube-dl and not ytdl-core (ytdl is defined as youtube-dl) Any thoughts on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Answer: I was using ytdl-core not ytdl-core-discord